# Will upgrading to Windows 10 make my caveman PC any faster?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, speed, desktop-computer

I own an old desktop PC, currently running Windows 7 32-bit, and I've noticed that it's running very slowly compared to lots of other more modern computers I use (I don't use any other computers as old as this one so have nothing to compare it to in that respect.)

I would like to know if upgrading to Windows 10 could bring any speed advantages, I'm currently worrying that maybe my PC is too old and outdated to handle this more modern Operating System which might put even more demands on its systems.

Here's what I was able to find out about my PC's current specs after doing some research and running `systeminfo.exe`:

```
Host Name:                 ********
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          ********
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                55041-011-2205912-86952
Original Install Date:     08/06/2012, 13:48:15
System Boot Time:          01/05/2016, 07:46:42
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              Inspiron 530
System Type:               X86-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: x64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6 GenuineIntel ~2667 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc. 1.0.15, 20/06/2008
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
Input Locale:              en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
Time Zone:                 (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
Total Physical Memory:     2,037 MB
Available Physical Memory: 254 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  4,074 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 1,476 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    2,598 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    HOME
Logon Server:              ********
Hotfix(s):                 496 Hotfix(s) Installed.
```

Of course, I'm extremely inexperienced in the realm of software and hardware compatibility so if you think any more information about my system would help improve this question then please suggest it.

I'd like to know if upgrading to Windows 10 would make my computer faster?

(An answer explaining other advantages/disadvantages of upgrading could also be helpful)

Comment: Is your copy of Windows 7 64 bit? It isn't clear from your specifications.

Comment: No, it is 32 bit.

Comment: @Burgi you cannot upgrade a 32 bit to 64 bit install. This always requires a fresh install.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see it was a link. my bad. You said: Convert the install. Technically its "do a fresh reinstall to 64 bit."

Comment: @Burgi Yes please, having answers is often an integral part of Question *and* Answer sites xD Humour aside though, I'd love any help I can get! Thank you for putting so much thought into this.

Comment: First question: is it actually running the same but your expectations have changed and it just seems slow?  If it has actually slowed significantly from when it was new, and especially if the change was recent, you can likely fix it without changing the OS.  Many things can slow down a computer, from bloat of loaded background programs to software conflicts to corruption to malware to failing hardware, etc.  There are lots of reasons to not load Win 10 if the only purpose is to try to gain speed.  Start with cleaning up what's there and/or reinstall Win 7 and build on it with discrimination.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a caveman computer, then you better know there are some downsides along with upgrading it to Windows 10, but first let's list your current system configuration.

**Current System Configuration:**

Processor: Intel® Core™ 2 Duo CPU @ 2.26GHz

RAMs: 2GB DDR2 SDRAM(667/800-MHz).

Video: Intel integrated video

**Bad news**, you CANNOT upgrade your RAMs more than 4GB since the Inspiron 530 has a 4GB RAM limit as well as the DDR2 SDRAM model is too old, and has a very slow performance comparing to the today's RAMs.

and if you want to know what downsides you'll experience, simply it will be some hangs and slow performance since Windows 10 will work on an old hardware that supposed to be forgotten. Also, some hardware drivers might have some compatibility issues on Windows 10, others are going to be working without a problem or can have updated versions and can be downloaded from the manufacture website or from Windows Updates. [Check out this article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/will-your-pc-run-windows-10-use-this-well-hidden-compatibility-checker-to-find-out/). Other than that, you're good.

**Good news**, your CPU is 64-bit, thus, you can benefit from Windows 64-bit system. While you can also use the PCI-Express slot to add a graphics card that will replace the OLD integrated GPU and help to increase your system performance a bit.Also, make sure that your computer hardware is dust-free before you do anything else.

**Conclusion**

Your computer can be upgraded to Windows 10, but you need to use Windows 10 64-bit along with adding a dedicated GPU with no less than 512MB of VRAM. You can even add/replace the hard drive to something fits your needs, just keep in mind, this computer will handle only a light usage such as browsing, office, and normal usage, but it won't handle a heavy usage such as gaming and any program with high processing and rendering data.

Comment: A much better answer than mine, however I should point out that the OP *can* upgrade their RAM as they currently only have 2GB, they can at the very least double that. According to the manufacturer this machine has 4 RAM slots.

Comment: @Burgi crap, I just missed it :(, thanks for noticing that,and yes you're right. It's my fault that I didn't read it slower.

Comment: There is a possibility that some drivers for that model and W10 will not be available, its an experiment at best. Best option is to run the compatibility test using the get w10 app (gwx) before upgrading, it will flag any potential issues.

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/article/will-your-pc-run-windows-10-use-this-well-hidden-compatibility-checker-to-find-out/

Comment: @Moab agreed. may I add this point to the answer ? something like that it will be important to focus on.

Comment: Sure can, its why I commented, to help improve your answer without editing it myself.

Comment: @Moab thanks, I have updated the answer. Hope we covered it all as I know there is always something missing, that's why I like collaboration to fill in the gaps. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would make the upgrade even though it could be a little complex and long winded.

You are currently hampered on hardware upgrade options due to the 32 bit OS. While upgrading from Windows 7 32 bit will only give you a 32 bit version of Windows 10 it will allow you to create a Windows 10 64 bit installation disk as describe in [@Phoebeli](https://superuser.com/a/978339/393570) answer.

> Once upgrading your Windows 7/8.1 installation to Windows 10 and activating the copy, download the 64-bit Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft using the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool, create a bootable USB out of it and then install the 64-bit Windows 10.

You will need to backup all your data and perform a completely fresh installation. Now with your 64 bit OS in place you can add some more RAM to your system (at least 8GB), you should notice a significant improvement in general speed.

**Advantages**

- You will get Windows 10 and all future updates for free (The free upgrade offer is only available for a limited time only).
- Your CPU is 64 bit but can currently only make use of a maximum 4GB RAM due to the 32 bit OS. The upgrade option allows you then to get a 64 bit Windows OS legally and for free.

**Disadvantages**

- Loss of data during the migration of 32 bit to 64 bit. It is unlikely, especially if you do a proper backup of your settings folders and user directory but it is still a risk that you might miss something.
- Software compatibility, as with each new generation of Windows you may find that some legacy software just simply stops working. You could mitigate this risk by testing the software in a limited run Windows 10 VM from [Modern.ie](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/)
- You dislike the new look.